# Why does parallel transport along geodesics solve $\nabla_{r\partial_r}\tau=0$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, geodesic, connections

I understand the definition of parallel transport given the data $(M,E,\nabla,\gamma)$ and I understand the definition of geodesics given the data $(M,g)$. Given all of this data, we can make the following definitions:

Fix some $y\in M$ and consider a normal neighborhood $U$. Given some $x\in U$, we can consider the $\mathbf x\in T_yM$ defined by $\exp_y(\mathbf x)=x$ and in addition we can consider the geodesic $\gamma_x:[0,1]\to M$ defined by $\gamma_x(t)=\exp_y(t\mathbf x)$. Furthermore, for each $v\in E_y$ we can consider
$$\tau_v(x):=V(1)\in E_x,$$
where $V\in\Gamma([0,1],\gamma_x^*E)$ is the parallel transport of $v$ along $\gamma_x$.

Why does this solve $\nabla_{r\partial_r}\tau_v=0$ (as claimed in the proof of Theorem 2.26 in [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628))? Roughly speaking we have that $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}_x(1)}\tau_v=0$ (by the definition of parallel transport), so my guess would be that there is some correlation between the velocity of $\gamma$ and the radial vector field $\partial_r$. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: Parallel transport is a property of a curve $\gamma$ such that $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma} = 0$. Where does your radial vector field come from? Is it in the theorem?

Comment: @MichaelParis The radial vector field is defined on page $71$. In normal coordinates around $y$ we have $$r\partial_r:=x^i\partial_i.$$(Of course the sum is independent of the chosen orthonormal basis of $T_yM$.)

Comment: $r\partial_r$ is a vector field on $T_yM$, but it is being treated as the vector field $(\exp_y)_*(r\partial_r)$ on $M$ in the formula you’re asking about.

Comment: @Deane Does this mean that you disagree with my comment above your comment?

Comment: No, I don’t disagree. Your comment does essentially answer your own question.

Comment: @Deane Does the issue really boil down to $\forall x\in U:\dot{\gamma}_x(1)=x^i\partial_i(x)$?

Comment: Yes, it does boil down to that.

Comment: @Deane Thank you for the comments. I was somehow convinced that the issue requires some advanced knowledge, but now I see that the equation is super obvious in view of the definition of $\gamma$ and normal coordinates.

Comment: @Filippo, I'm happy to see that you were able to figure this out yourself. Even super obvious things can be hard to see.